# Clarifying with references if malloc() allocates or not contiguous memory on every system

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the K&R book, chapter 8, it is explained how *malloc()* creates a list of blocks in the free memory, each pointing to the next one (roughly speaking), that **don't need to be contiguous**.
On the other hand, everybody claims that malloc() allocates memory in a contiguous way, I see pointer arithmetic massively used, and similar quetsions are on this website. **But, always without any official source**.

I read the C reference and found no mention about the contiguity, and the best that I found was on the Linux and Windows man pages where they ensure this property on *their* systems.

Therefore: does *malloc()* offer contiguous memory (e.g. making then pointer arithmetic legal) just on canonical modern system, or is it a rule governed by the > C89 standard, which I naively overlooked? Please, provide an official reference. Thank you.

Ps: this is not just a theoretical question. I am writing some code for an old DOS system, and I need to be sure about the proper usage of *malloc*.

EDIT: I understand my mistake now, thanks. That said, I still don't manage to find an official resource where it is clearly stated that a single *malloc()* call returns contiguous memory (Why isn't this information simply included below the function description, in the standard library...?) For instance, no trace here (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).

Comment: A single `malloc` call returns a contiguous block of memory. But multiple calls to `malloc` don't have to return adjacent blocks (which is what K&R meant).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help! May I ask where did you find that a single malloc call returns a contiguous block? I literally have the book and the reference in front of me, and I don't see that!

Comment: I don't know where it's explicitly specified, but `malloc` would be unusable if this wasn't the case.

Comment: @user47 I haven't now the C89 on hand, but i can tell you to read the chapter 5.4 (_5.4 Address Arithmetic_) of the book that clearly defines what is an allocated block of memory.

Comment: Argh, in the draft that I found (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) there is no section 5.4. And actually, I still don't manage to find the info that a single call provides contiguous memory. Why isn't it simply included in the description of malloc() itself? Eh...

Comment: @user47 In this draft, look at _7.20.3 Memory management functions_, The statements _"and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects"_ and  _"The pointer returned points to the start (lowest byte address) of the allocated space"_ implies adjacent addresses. Accessing _objects_ as an array of _objects_ in the allocated space would not be possible without adjacent addresses.

Comment: @Zilog80 Yes, I see! If you can access the allocated block in the same way you access an array, it must have adjacent addresses. I totally agree, thank you! But honestly, I think they could have been a bit more explicit about that, or at least mention in the standard library under the malloc description... :-)

Comment: @interjay think about lists in Python: the indexing list[n] makes sense, so that you can   use them as "arrays" despite being allocated sparsely in the memory. I was thinking something like: "maybe, under the hood, C treats array[n] like Python lists when the allocation is done with malloc, and with simpler arithmetic addressing when not". Convoluted, but doable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess i can cite the book related passage :

> Rather than allocating from a compiled-in fixed-size array, malloc will request space from
> the operating system as needed. Since other activities in the program may also request space
> without calling this allocator, the space that malloc manages may not be contiguous. Thus its
> free storage is kept as a list of free blocks. Each block contains a size, a pointer to the next
> block, and the space itself. The blocks are kept in order of increasing storage address, and the
> last block (highest address) points to the first.

You are misunderstanding it, it tells that each malloc successive calls will not be necessarily all contiguous allocated space. That doesn't mean that one allocated bloc is not contiguous. And, in fact, with today OS and modern CPU  there is a also a [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) in the game, i suggest you to read about that.

Comment: Oh, yes yes yes, now I clearly see what was the issue! I understood each block to be just a _single_ byte of memory, therefore the need of jumping between them. Rather, each block is _already_ composed by enough contiguous cells to cover the user request. Then, when malloc is repeated, it returns another block in another location. So the various blocks are sparse, but each of them is internally contiguous and corresponds to a single call. Thanks for your help, I am very grateful!

Answer (score 5):

The quote means that if you will call malloc several times then it is not necessary that the allocated blocks are adjacent.

But in each call of malloc it allocates a single extent of memory of adjacent bytes. If it can not do that it returns a null pointer.

From the C Standard (7.22.3 Memory management functions)

> 1 The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to
> the aligned_alloc, calloc, malloc, and realloc functions is
> unspecified. The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
> suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type
> of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to
> access such an object or an array of such objects in the space
> allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated)...

Comment: Thank you for the reference, my mistake! Your answer helped a lot, but the other one gave me a clearer overview (so I gave you +1, but marked the other with the green label).